# grep String in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using GREP to subset data frame into multiple data frame

```
Test = Other[ grep("Hi", Other$`Summary`),]
```

the about code works fine. But I want to grep "PING"

```
PING = Other[ grep("PING", Other$`Summary`),]
```

the above statement greps all records where every it finds PING. 
But I want to grep only if the word starts with PING

Is there a way to do it.

Comment: Use `^PING` instead of `PING`.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=grep%20beginning%20string

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=grep+beginning+string+r

Comment: @ytk this works if the sentence starts with PING, What if the word PING is middle of the Sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `\\b` as suggested along with `.*\\b` to indicate the end of the word begining in "PING"

```
Other[grep("\\bPING.*\\b", Other$`Summary`,perl=T),]
```

Comment: Thank bro,
It works perfectly fine for me. Can you explain me what is "perl=T" or like where i can get the explanation.

Comment: Essentially `\\b` and `.*` are a form of regular expressions (often referred to as regex or regexp). `perl=T` tells R that you are using regular expressions to convey what you want to grep

Comment: Got it, Thank you !!

Comment: R understands regex without specifying the `perl` argument. Perl has a few differences in syntax for some regex expressions, so you would use `perl=T` for any expressions native to perl

Answer (score 3):

We can use `^` to indicate the start of the string.

```
Other[grep("\\bPING", Other$`Summary`),]
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply 
The About Code works if the Sentence starts with PING,
But I'm looking for Word that starts with PING,its can be any where in the Sentence

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan  THen use the word boundary `\\b`.